# How to call an Extended interface function with base Interface reference?

Tags: java, oop, interface

Sorry if my question did not make any sense. I will try to explain it here. Let's say I have a base interface like this :

```
public interface SimpleInterface {
    public void function1(); 
}
```

And an extended interface as follows :

```
public interface ExtendedInterface extends SimpleInterface{
    public void function2();
}
```

Lets say I have a class which implements `ExtendedInterface` :

```
public class Implementation implements ExtendedInterface {

    @Override
    public void function1() {
        System.out.println("function1");
    }

    @Override
    public void function2() {
        System.out.println("function2");
    }
}
```

Now is there any way I can call `function2()` when I'm given a base interface (`SimpleInterface`) which is instantiated with `Implementation` class, like this:

```
SimpleInterface simpleInterface = new Implementation();
```

I know it defeats the purpose of interfaces but it would save me from doing a lot of code changes.

Comment: If you want simpleInterface to give you access to the function2 method, its type should simply be ExtendedInterface, not SimpleInterface. Casting like the answers suggest defeats the whole purpose

Answer (score 4):

You'd have to cast to `ExtendedInterface`, basically:

```
SimpleInterface simpleInterface = new Implementation();
ExtendedInterface extendedInterface = (ExtendedInterface) simpleInterface;
extendedInterface.function2();
```

Of course, the cast will fail if the object that `simpleInterface` refers to doesn't *actually* implement `ExtendedInterface`. The need to do this is definitely a code smell - it *may* be the best option available to you, but it's at least worth considering alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

First you should check if the object instance is actually an implementation of Implementation class as that could be the case that more than one classes are implementing this Interface.

You can do it as below:

```
//Somewhere in the code 
SimpleInterface simpleInterface = new Implementation();

//Now with the variable you can check it as below
if(simpleInterface instanceof Implementation)
Implementation implemenation = (Implementation)simpleInterface;
implemenation.function2();
```

Answer (score 1):

The methods that can be called are restricted by the left-hand type (`SimpleInterface`) and because `SimpleInterface` does not have a method `function2()`, `function2()` cannot be called on the `simpleInterface` object.

In order to do this, a cast (specifically, a [downcast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downcasting)) as follows:

```
ExtendedInterface extendedInterface = (ExtendedInterface) simpleInterface;
extendedInterface.function2();
```

Or, more succinctly:

```
((ExtendedInterface) simpleInterface).function2()
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by other's casting is an option but it is not full proof. We can use reflection here

```
    Method[] methods = simpleInterface.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
    for (Method method : methods) {
        if (method.getName().equals("function2"))

        try {
                method.invoke(simpleInterface);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }
```

Using the above code will ensure that `function2` method is called on a reference of the object which has this method